# To generate grids within a square area in python

Tags: python-3.x, grid

I have a square layout of size `100*100`. I want to divide this layout into grids of size `5*5`.How can I do so using python?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve. Are u making a GUI? How did u achieve the 100*100 layout? What is the endgoal of this programm?

Comment: It is not for a GUI, I want to allocate nodes in these grids with different densities. To be able to do that, I want to keep a tab of the locations and the corresponding grid number.

Comment: what sort of output are u expecting from this? Do you want to create a function that can take a gridsize and return a list with all the nodes? I still dont quiet understand what you mean with "corresponding grid number"? Do you want to give a index (e.g 400) and get the node (e.g (20,20)?

Comment: Yes, create a function that can take the grid size and return a list with all the nodes. I basically want to allocate resources to each of these grids and then plot them based on the density of the resource in each grid.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure this is what you are looking for, so correct me if this is not it.
I assumed the best way to deal with the problem you described is by creating a `Grid` class. That makes it easier to create mulitple diffrent Grids at the same time without making a mess with the data. Ive come up with this solution:

```
class Grid():
    def __init__(self,x,y,grid_len):
        self.total_x = x
        self.total_y = y
        self.grid_len = grid_len
        self.node_list=[]
        for y in range(self.total_y//self.grid_len):
             for x in range(self.total_x//self.grid_len):
                self.node_list.append((x*self.grid_len,y*self.grid_len))

    def return_node_at_given_x_y(self,x,y):
        node_index = y*(self.total_y//self.grid_len) + x
        print(self.node_list[node_index])


my_grid = Grid(100,100,5)
print(my_grid.return_node_at_given_x_y(8,6))
#print(my_grid.node_list)
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. U can change the size of your base square or of the grids when creating the object. `Grid(200,200,2)` will have a grid_size of 2 and a square size of 200x200.